# How to re-implement legacy aspx with ServiceStack and maintain the address?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, servicestack

Is it possible to keep the following address and re-implement it with ServiceStack?

```
http://example.com/Routing/LeadPost.aspx?LeadType=AAA&MYId=3000
```

I don't have access to the original code as it was a 3rd party who created it, but I do know what the post to it, a gigantic xml package. This I have mimicked perfectly with a clean request DTO and service, but I'm not clear on the addressing part, or if it's even plausible. Below is my implementation so far.

```
public class Service : ServiceStack.Service
{
    public IMessageQueueClient MessageQueueClient { get; set; }

    public object Post(LeadInformation request)
    {
        if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        MessageQueueClient.Publish(request);

        return new LeadInformationResponse
        {
            TimeTakenMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
        };
    }
}
```

Thank you,
 Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this route definition to handle the Legacy ASP.NET WebForms Request:

```
[Route("/Routing/LeadPost.aspx")]
public class LegacyLeadPost
{
    public string LeadType { get; set; }
    public int MyId { get; set; }
}
```

Which will let you handle the desired route with `LeadType` and `MyId` properties populated:

```
/Routing/LeadPost.aspx?LeadType=AAA&MYId=3000
```

An alternative approach is to use a WebForms Page and call into ServiceStack, the [ServiceStack Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration) docs explores the different ways from accessing ServiceStack from external ASP.NET MVC or WebForms Web Frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed ServiceStack (at least up to version 3, which is what I last used), it adds something to your application's `Web.Config file` that looks like:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="somePath/*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

If you modify the `path` attribute to match your legacy URL, it may work. Then again, without knowing what other `HttpHandler`s are set up for your application, it is impossible to tell for sure. Also keep in mind that you may introduce conflicts, because there is an `HttpHandler` that passes all `.aspx` urls to the .NET webforms `Page` base class and all the other code-behind files in your application.